# How to convert daily sales transactions into monthly data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date, group-by, sum

```
Date    Amount
1/2/2018    149
1/2/2018    50
1/2/2018    300
1/2/2018    50
1/3/2018    50
1/3/2018    50
1/3/2018    150
1/3/2018    150
1/3/2018    150
1/3/2018    300
1/4/2018    125
1/4/2018    129
1/4/2018    149
1/4/2018    250
```

Above is the data I am working with. I would like to turn this data into monthly sales but am having trouble with my code. Do I need to first define the date? Below is what I have so far but am getting these results and not the sum for amount.

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)

df.resample('MS').sum()



Date            Year
2018-01-01  131016.0
2018-02-01  147121.0
2018-03-01  167221.0
2018-04-01  187418.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has to problems i think, dates have to defined like this `"1-1-2018"` and second to transform a column to datetime this is the syntax `df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])`

Comment: Thank you for your input! I realized I also needed to change the 'Amount' data type from object to float and it resolved my issue.